# What would happen if you were to release the energies of the big bang in our universe a second time?

Tags: energy, cosmology, big-bang

Would it just wipe out everything, or would something else occur?

Comment: We don't know how much energy was released in total. Some people think that the total energy balance of the universe is zero. What would happen if you release zero energy? Nothing.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Should we tolerate _what-if_ questions?

Comment: @user36790: Depends on the question, I would say. I am not making the rules around here and if I find a question really bad, I am voting it down. This one is a borderline case because one can answer it in meaningful ways, in my opinion. I hinted at a possible scenario in my comment that one would have to consider seriously and there are others that I wouldn't want to discuss because I don't know enough about cosmology at the quantum level. Someone else might bring those up. Or maybe there are enough who think that this isn't even remotely close to physics... I could live with that, too.

Comment: This question does not really make sense because the big bang was not a "release of energy", see also [Did the big bang happen at a  point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/50583).

Answer (score 1):

> What would happen if you were to release the energies of the big bang in our universe a second time?

Have a look at [this standard  history](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31825049) of the universe,

[image: BB]

> [History of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) - gravitational waves are hypothesized to arise from cosmic inflation, an expansion just after the Big Bang

Our universe is now at the far right. Note the beginning at far left where all the energy is concentrated in the inflation period.

If you introduce something like that  inflation discontinuity at the far left, in our current universe on the far right, it will eat it up as a black hole attracts all the surrounding matter. It will be a very strong gravitational well. How fast everything would disappear for us is dependent on where this materializes. If next to us, immediately. If some light years away, it will take some years.